# Get the font height of a character in PDFBox

Tags: java, fonts, font-size, pdfbox

There is a method in PDFBox's font class, PDFont, named getFontHeight which sounds simple enough. However I don't quite understand the documentation and what the parameters stand for.

> [`getFontHeight`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html#getFontHeight%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)
>   This will get the font width for a character.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - c - The character code to get the width for.
> - offset - The offset into the array.  length
> - The length of the data.
>
> **Returns:**  The width is in 1000 unit of text space, ie 333 or 777

Is this method the right one to use to get the height of a character in PDFBox and if so how? Is it some kind of relationship between font height and font size I can use instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the answer marked right requires some additional clarification. There are no "error" per font for getHeight() and hence I believe it is not a good practice manually guessing the coefficient for each new font.
Guess it could be nice for your purposes simply use CapHeight instead of Height.

```
float height = ( font.getFontDescriptor().getCapHeight()) / 1000 * fontSize;
```

That will return the value similar to what you are trying to get by correcting the Height with 0.865 for Helvetica. But it will be universal for any font.

PDFBox docs do not explain too much what is it. But you can look at the image in the wikipedia Cap_height article to understand better how it is working and choose the parameter fit to your particular task.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_height

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Cap height was what I was looking for. See the accepted answer.

After digging through the source of PDFBox I found that this should do the trick of calculating the font height.

```
int fontSize = 14;
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize
```

The method isn't perfect though. If you draw a rectangle with the height 200 and a Y with the font size 200 you get the font height 231.2 calculated with the above method even though it actually is printed smaller then the rectangle.

Every font has a different error but with helvetica it is close to 13.5 precent too much independently of font size. Therefore, to get the right font height for helvetica this works...

```
font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize * 0.865
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this?

http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/TextPosition.html

Seems like a wrap-around util for text. I haven't looked in the source if it accounts for font error though.

Answer (score 0):

this is a working method for splitting the text and finding the height

```
public float heightForWidth(float width) throws IOException {
    float height = 0;

    String[] split = getTxt().split("(?<=\\W)");
    int[] possibleWrapPoints = new int[split.length];
    possibleWrapPoints[0] = split[0].length();
    for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
        possibleWrapPoints[i] = possibleWrapPoints[i - 1] + split[i].length();
    }

    float leading = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    for (int i : possibleWrapPoints) {
        float w = font.getStringWidth(getTxt().substring(start, i)) / 1000 * fontSize;
        if (start < end && w > width) {
            height += leading;
            start = end;
        }
        end = i;
    }

    height += leading;
    return height + 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For imported True Type Fonts the total height of the font is

`(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getFontDescriptor().getDescent() + org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getFontDescriptor().getAscent() + org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getFontDescriptor().getLeading()) * point size * org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getFontMatrix().getValue(0, 0)`

You will find that `font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight()` is 20% larger than the above value as it includes a 20% leading on the above value, but if you take the top value and remove 20%, the font will be right next too each other

Comment: There are multiple issues in your formula: *(A)* The **Descent** is a negative number; for your formula to make any sense its absolute value (i.e. `-...getFontDescriptor().getDescent()`) should be used. *(B)* For determining the **Ascent** the height of glyphs for accented characters are excluded; if you consider accented characters part of the font, therefore, the formula cannot be right. Furthermore you include a `point size` without explaining it. This value is not trivial.