# Annotations placed by word coordinates shifted

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am developing a program that will add annotations over specific words that are found in a document. The annotations appear to be the right size, the X coordinates are pretty close (not perfect) but the Y coordinate is shifted considerably. My assumption here is that the coordinate systems are different but it's not clear how to adjust the Y coordinates to place it correctly.

Here is the code, the most important method is placeAnnotations()

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationTextMarkup;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Sample {

    private static final float FROM_72_TO_300_DPI = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));

        try {
            //insert new page
            PDPage page = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);

            List<WordBBox> words = getWords(doc, 0);

            placeAnnotations(words, page);

            doc.save("test-out.pdf");

        } finally {
            doc.close();
        }
    }


    public static List<WordBBox> getWords(PDDocument document, int page) throws IOException {

        CustomPDFTextStripper customPDFTextStripper = new CustomPDFTextStripper();
        customPDFTextStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        customPDFTextStripper.setStartPage(page);
        customPDFTextStripper.setEndPage(page + 1);

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        customPDFTextStripper.writeText(document, writer);

        List<WordBBox> words = customPDFTextStripper.getWords();

        return words;
    }

    private static void placeAnnotations(List<WordBBox> words, PDPage page) throws IOException {
        
        List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
        for (WordBBox word : words) {


            if (word.word.toLowerCase().equals("simple") || word.word.toLowerCase().equals("pdf")) {
                //generate instanse for annotation
                PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);

                //set the rectangle
                PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
                position.setLowerLeftX(word.x);
                position.setLowerLeftY(word.y + word.height);
                position.setUpperRightX(word.x + word.width);
                position.setUpperRightY(word.y);
                txtMark.setRectangle(position);


                //set the quadpoint
                float[] quads = new float[8];
                //x1,y1
                quads[0] = position.getLowerLeftX();
                quads[1] = position.getUpperRightY();
                //x2,y2
                quads[2] = position.getUpperRightX();
                quads[3] = quads[1];
                //x3,y3
                quads[4] = quads[0];
                quads[5] = position.getLowerLeftY();
                //x4,y4
                quads[6] = quads[2];
                quads[7] = quads[5];

                txtMark.setRectangle(position);
                txtMark.setQuadPoints(quads);
                txtMark.setAnnotationName("My annotation - " + word.word);
                txtMark.setTitlePopup("For '" + word.word + "'");
                txtMark.setContents("Highlighted since it's important for word '" + word.word + "'");
                txtMark.setRichContents("Here is some rich content for the word '" + word.word + "'");
                PDColor blue = new PDColor(new float[]{0, 0, 1}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
                txtMark.setColor(blue);
                txtMark.setInvisible(false);
                txtMark.setNoView(false);
                txtMark.setNoZoom(false);
                txtMark.setLocked(false);
                txtMark.setHidden(false);
                txtMark.constructAppearances();

                annotations.add(txtMark);

            }

        }

        page.setAnnotations(annotations);

    }

    private static class CustomPDFTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper {

        private final List<WordBBox> words;

        public CustomPDFTextStripper() throws IOException {
            this.words = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public List<WordBBox> getWords() {
            return new ArrayList<>(words);
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {

            String wordSeparator = getWordSeparator();
            List<TextPosition> wordTextPositions = new ArrayList<>();

            for (TextPosition textPosition : textPositions) {
                String str = textPosition.getUnicode();
                if (wordSeparator.equals(str)) {
                    if (!wordTextPositions.isEmpty()) {
                        this.words.add(createWord(wordTextPositions));
                        wordTextPositions.clear();
                    }
                } else {
                    wordTextPositions.add(textPosition);
                }
            }

            super.writeString(text, textPositions);
        }

        private WordBBox createWord(List<TextPosition> wordTextPositions) {

            String word = wordTextPositions.stream()
                    .map(TextPosition::getUnicode)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());

            int minX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int minY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int maxX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int maxY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            for (TextPosition wordTextPosition : wordTextPositions) {

                minX = Math.min(minX, from72To300Dpi(wordTextPosition.getXDirAdj()));
                minY = Math.min(minY, from72To300Dpi(wordTextPosition.getYDirAdj() - wordTextPosition.getHeightDir()));
                maxX = Math.max(maxX, from72To300Dpi(wordTextPosition.getXDirAdj() + wordTextPosition.getWidthDirAdj()));
                maxY = Math.max(maxY, from72To300Dpi(wordTextPosition.getYDirAdj()));
            }

            return new WordBBox(word, minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
        }
    }

    private static int from72To300Dpi(float f) {
        return Math.round(f * FROM_72_TO_300_DPI);
    }

    private static class WordBBox {
        private String word = null;
        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;
        private int width = 0;
        private int height = 0;

        public WordBBox(String word, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.word = word;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

    }
}
```

The PDF I am using to test is here: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

As you can see in this screenshot the annotations are at the bottom of the page, when they should be placed over the words 'Simple' and 'PDF'

[image]

Comment: Instead of `getXDirAdj()` and `getYDirAdj()` use `getTextMatrix().getTranslateX()` and `getTextMatrix().getTranslateY()`, and even then there sometimes is a need for correction, read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46080131/1729265).

Comment: Cool thank you that looks promising